# Crystal Report - Sub report section is not growing with the field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a subreport in the detail section of a report. The subreport has two fields in the details section with 'Can Grow' is set to true and the each one is kept in different section in order to avoid text overlapping. The field is growing but the section is not growing with the field so only partial text appears while printing. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Craig. The 'Can Grow' was already set to true for the subreport.  I found another solution which really does not relate to logic but it worked. I increased the height of the subreport somewhat equal to the height of the pageheader + at least one detail section + pagefooter of the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

Mark sure to mark the subreport as "Can Grow".