# Crystal Reports: Repeating main report to display remaining subreport records

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

As basic/clearly as I can put it:
-I have a subreport located in a 'details b' section within a main report (the main report data is displayed in the 'details a' section) that is constrained to display 10 records per page. The subreport displays records based on the record returned by the main report (I think that is probably pretty typical, but figure I should mention it).

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the subreport returns >10 records the report would repeat the info it returned from the main report on the next page, and then display the remaining subreport records in the designated area.

My problem is that all it does is display the first 10 records of the subreport and the remaining records are nowhere to be found (assumably they are there, but outside of the designated area).

I'm using Crystal Reports XI.

[image: CR Design]
[image: With the records that it returns]

Comment: How many pages are there in report preview?

Comment: At the moment I only have the main report focused on a single record with a verified 11 subreport records returned. The report currently only displays 1 page in the preview, which is the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable 'Can grow' option and then check and if not work then move to footer section with 'Can grow'. Just try this, ideally it shows the data.

check this link.

[Crystal Report - Sub report section is not growing with the field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15782328/crystal-report-sub-report-section-is-not-growing-with-the-field)

http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=216817

http://p2p.wrox.com/access-vba/73894-report-growing-sub-report.html